# Executing List of soql count() queries in apex class

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, count

I've a Map of SOQL count queries, is there any way to execute the whole list(Map Values) of queries and get result in to a map.

```
    Map<String,String> countQueryMap=new Map<String,String>();
    Map<String,Integer> countResultMap=new Map<String,Integer>(); //Map<objName,Count>
    countQueryList.put('Account','SELECT COUNT() FROM Account');
    countQueryList.put('Contact','SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact');
    countQueryList.put('Abc','SELECT COUNT() FROM Abc__c');
    countQueryList.put('Xyz','SELECT COUNT() FROM Xyz__c');
```

Comment: This isn't a question...what is it you're stuck on exactly?

Comment: I am having a list of count queries for different objects that gets constructed dynamically, but I dont want a SOQL in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

[COUNT()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) aggregate function is available only in SOQL, but not in SOSL. SOSL, but not SOQL can return multiple types of object as a result of one query. As a result of these statements - no, you can't count number of records of different types in one query.

in this case you can do the following (warning, SOQL query in loops!!!):

```
Set<SObjectType> countQuerySet = new Set<SObjectType>();
Map<SObjectType,Integer> countResultMap = new Map<SObjectType,Integer>();
countQuerySet.add(Account.SObjectType);
countQuerySet.add(Contact.SObjectType);

for(SObjectType sobjType :countQuerySet){
    Integer count = (Integer) Database.query(
        'select count(Id)cnt ' +
        'from ' + String.valueOf(sobjType)
        ).get(0).get('cnt');
    countResultMap.put(sobjType, count);
}
```

From example, you didn't mentioned that there is a difference between count queries for Sobjects, that is why i changed `Map` to `Set`.